# Standard Style for Infrastructure

Tags: symbology, infrastructure

I'm trying to locate or find out if there is a standard style for municipal infrastructure.  Specifically Canadian (Provincial BC, AB) standards for symbolizing water, sewer, valves, hydrants etc.

Answer (score 2):

Got these from the [Natural Resources Canada web site](http://atlas.nrcan.gc.ca/site/english/maps/topo/topo_legend.html/). It has most of the symbols you need.

[image]

[image]

As for the exact symbols, I found this [answer from an ESRI forum](http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=ask.answers&q=2100) which I think is a good answer so I'll just post it here anyway for the benefit of people who are seeking the same information.

> **Mapping Center Answer:**
>
> We would suggest starting with the information available through the
>   (CGDI) Canadian Geospatial Data Infrastructure site. Searching for
>   styles specific to industry standards would be something that ESRI
>   Canada may have links to through their customer support. There is a
>   very good recent white paper article called ESRI Technology for the
>   Canadian Geospatial Data Infrastructure (CGDI) that explains the
>   effort to organized Canadian GIS standards.
>
> As an example, if you are looking for standards specific to Canadian
>   structures, (examples: Provincial BC, AB) for  symbolizing water,
>   sewer, hydrants etc, it may be somewhat challenging to find specific
>   styles -- many are kept as assets that are not shared by the authoring
>   organization and are considered proprietary. We would go with trying
>   through the ESRI Canada site and see if they can put you in contact
>   with the individual government entities that are in charge.